# How to make a web app appear at the root of the site?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, punbb

I have a bulletin board (punBB based) that I was running out of the root directory for a couple of years. I foolishly decided to do a little gardening and in the process moved the punbb code into it's own subdirectory. The code works great; as long as you point the browser at the new subdirectory. The issue is that the users expect to see it at the root...

I tried an index file in the root that had the following:

```
<?php chdir('punbb');
include('index.php');
```

But that didn't seem to do the trick. So, I tried using the "damn cool voodoo" of mod_rewrite in .htaccess but I can't seem to figure out the right combination of rules to make it work.

Here is what I would like to make happen:

User enters:

```
 http://guardthe.net
```

Browser displays:

```
 http://guardthe.net/punbb/
```

or

```
 http://punbb.guardthe.net/
```

Is this possible, or should I just move the code base back into the root?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this in .htacces should do it:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /punbb/ [R=301,L]
```

The 301 return code is to mark the move as permanentm making it posible for the browser to update bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

a PHP file with a 301 HTTP permenant redirect.

Put the following into index.php in the root directory of guardthe.net

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://guardthe.net/punbb/" );
?>
```

browser will re-direct with search engine friendliness.

Comment: Unless there is no mod_rewrite support on your server, you should avoid this approach as the user must download this web page and have the browser display it before executing a second transaction back to the server. The delay is usually long enough for the user to notice. Go for mod_rewrite if poss.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is missing but here's one way to do it using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://guardthe.net/punbb/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Just a note to clarify:
This would need to be in the webroot's .htaccess file, (not within the the punbb directory).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small redirect script to take care of this simply and quickly.

```
<?php 
header( 'Location: http://guardthe.net/punbb/' ); 
?>
```

Enter that as the only content in your index.php in your root directory, and any requests sent to that folder will then redirect the user to the forum.